# 2D BoundingRectangle rotation in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, xna-4.0, bounding-box

I'm having trouble working out what I need to do in order to have a 2D BoundingRectangle for a sprite object in my game rotate and update position depending on which way the user wants the sprite to travel.

I draw out the sprite with it's rotation and scale values like so:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

My current setup for getting the BoundingRectangle is:

```
public Rectangle BoundingRectangle
{
    get { return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height); }
}
```

The above is very basic and obviously won't rotate with the sprite.
I've read a few QA posts and tried various things but none of them seem to achieve what I'm after or create very odd behaviours.

I'd be grateful for some suggestions on what I need to do.

Comment: Do you want your rectangle to rotate too, or still be a bounding box that's alligned to the x/y axes? (AABB)

Comment: I need a bounding box for collision detection which is based on the area covered by the rotated sprite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rectangle class doesn't contain rotation information, so you need some structure to contain that.

A good choice would be to return a list of four points, which are based on the rectangle you are now returning and the rotation applied to it.

You can apply apply a rotation on a set of points using the [Matrix class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197911.aspx) like so:

```
var m = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle);
Vector3 rotatedVector = Vector3.Transform(vector, m);
```

If you want to rotate around a certain point, lets say the center of your sprite, a translation should also be done:

```
var rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle);
var translateTo = Matrix.CreateTranslation(vector);
var translateBack = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-vector);
var comnbined = translateTo * rotation * translateBack;
Vector3 rotatedVector = Vector3.Transform(vectorToRotate, combined);
```

Be sure to check out all the other transformations that can be done with a matrix, matrices are core elements in game/graphics development.

Comment: I'm attempting to implement your suggestion, I have loaded the Matrix class but it doesn't seem to recognise the `RotateAt` or `TransformPoints` methods.

Comment: @diggersworld My bad, my previous example was using the Matrix class in the Drawing2D namespace, I changed the example to use the default matrix structure in XNA.

Comment: No worries. I got that in now, just wondering as my game is 2D should I be using `Vector2.Transform` rather than `Vector3`?

Comment: Yes use Vector2 when you are doing 2D stuff. But even if you would have used Vector3, the results would be the same, the extra dimension would just be ignored.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm testing this out on a `20x20` sprite rotated by the center point `10,10`. When I rotate it it comes back with negative results when they should be positive, i.e. for top left corner rotations I would expect `0,0`, `0,40`, `40,40`, `40,0` when going counter clockwise. Instead though they're negative.

Comment: I've changed to this `translateTo * rotation * translateBack` which now gives the positive values I would expect to see.