# How to rotate a bounding box in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to rotate a bounding box in xna, this is how I usually do it:

```
    new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)texture.Width, (int)texture.Height);
```

but It currently *does not* return the rotation that is in my draw code:

```
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

how do I rotate it with the player? I was trying to figure this out and stumbled across this:

[2D BoundingRectangle rotation in XNA 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552490/2d-boundingrectangle-rotation-in-xna-4-0)

but I'm not quite sure how to implement the Matrices he's talking about,and I'm making a 2d game as opposed to the 3d one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Rectangle` structure is an *axis aligned* bounding rectangle. The sides will always be parallel to the X and Y axes. If you want a rotated bounding rectangle you have to implement it yourself.

One algorithm for calculating collision of rotated rectangles is the [Separating Axis Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem).

Matrices are, as stated in the linked answer, essential in computer graphics. You can rotate a shape by rotating each of its vertices with the same rotation matrix. This is the general [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions) for two dimensions:

[image: R(theta) = [cos(theta), -sin(theta); sin(theta), cos(theta)]

Matrices are then "applied" to vectors with matrix-vector multiplication:

[image: P' = R(theta) * P]

which equals

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for two days before finding the solution

[Rotating bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438711/xna-bounding-box-rotation-nightmare)

Hope this will help !